# Labels not getting wrapped for fixed width

Tags: html, css, angular2-highcharts

I have developed a Pie chart in my application and below is the plnkr for my pie chart. I am able to display the legend properly, but couldn't able to wrap the text as shown in the plnkr. I tried worwrap, break word but it didnt work.

https://plnkr.co/edit/yzXLz7AIDoWa1Pzxxl4k?p=preview

Labels code:

```
'<div style="width:180px"><span class="pull-left" style= "font-weight: 500; padding-bottom: 5px">' + this.name +
                    '</span><span class="pull-right" style= "font-weight: 500" >' + this.value +
                    '</span></div> '
```

Comment: is the labels code something you wrote? or is it generated?

Comment: Its my own custom code